# Getting System.InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code exception

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms, entity-framework-core

I've got a Xamarin Forms project using EF Core 2.2.4 with SQLite. In a number of different places in my code I get a transient error (maybe 1% of the time?) that seems like an EF Core bug, but I can't say for sure.

One sample of code where I get this is:

```
var context = new DatabaseContext();
var dbItem = await context.MobileErrors.FirstOrDefaultAsync(me => me.Id.Equals(item.Id)).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

DatabaseContext inherits from DbContext. The exception also happens with ToListAsync() and other EF calls. The exception is:

> System.InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code in (wrapper
>   dynamic-method) object:lambda_method
>   (System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure): method body is empty.
>   at (wrapper managed-to-native)
>   System.Delegate.CreateDelegate_internal(System.Type,object,System.Reflection.MethodInfo,bool)
>   at System.Delegate.CreateDelegate (System.Type type, System.Object
>   firstArgument, System.Reflection.MethodInfo method, System.Boolean
>   throwOnBindFailure, System.Boolean allowClosed) [0x002f0] in
>   <58604b4522f748968296166e317b04b4>:0    at
>   System.Delegate.CreateDelegate (System.Type type, System.Object
>   firstArgument, System.Reflection.MethodInfo method) [0x00000] in
>   <58604b4522f748968296166e317b04b4>:0    at
>   System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod.CreateDelegate (System.Type
>   delegateType, System.Object target) [0x0001a] in
>   <58604b4522f748968296166e317b04b4>:0    at (wrapper dynamic-method)
>   System.Object.lambda_method(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryContext)
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.ExecuteSingletonAsyncQuery[TResult]
>   (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryContext queryContext,
>   System.Func`2[T,TResult] compiledQuery,
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics.IDiagnosticsLogger`1[TLoggerCategory]
>   logger, System.Type contextType) [0x000d6] in
>   :0    at
>   Mobile.Services.MobileErrorsService.UpdateLocalAsync
>   (Mobile.Data.Models.DatabaseContext context,
>   Mobile.Data.Models.MobileError item) [0x00133] in
>   :0    at
>   Mobile.Services.MobileErrorsService+<>c__DisplayClass8_0.b__0 ()
>   [0x00115] in :0

Any ideas of changes I could try to resolve this issue? Thanks!

Comment: may this be helpful,
This issue Originally posted as [aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore#14429](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/14429).
Then moved  to [mono/mono#12626](https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/12626)

Comment: Thank you for that, it does sound like others are hitting the same issue we are. Unfortunately since it is so hard to reproduce I can't provide any code to help them solve it. At least I know it seems to be a bug with EF Core and hopefully they get it worked out before too long.

Comment: Glad it helped, keep going